# Как в __init__ обратиться к классу, например, если тот может наследоваться?

Tags: python, ооп, классы

```py
class Parrent:
    varOfClass = None
    def __init__(self):
        Parrent.varOfClass = 1234 #?????
        #self.class.varOfClass = 1234 ?????

class ChildClass(Parrent):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__(self)
```

У меня есть класс с переменной, которая участвует в методах класса, но необходимо, чтобы наследники класса пользовались переменной с идентичным названием, но сами в себе, и не трогали класс родителя, как это можно осуществить?

Comment: Нужна именно переменная класса или переменная объекта? Приведите пример как это в наследниках будет использоваться, пока не особо понятно что именно вы хотите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `type(self)` или `self.__class__`:

```
class Parent:
    varOfClass = None
    def __init__(self):
        type(self).varOfClass = 1234
        # Или то же самое
        # self.__class__.varOfClass = 1234

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        type(self).varOfClass = 5678
        # Или то же самое
        # self.__class__.varOfClass = 5678


Parent()
Child()

print(Parent.varOfClass)
print(Child.varOfClass)
```

или, возможно, более ясным способом будет вынести манипуляции с переменными класса в `classmethod`, и дёргать его из `__init__`:

```
class Child(Parent):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_class_vars()
    
    @classmethod
    def set_class_vars(cls):
        cls.varOfClass = 5678
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать условно-приватный атрибут:

```
class Parent:
    __varOfClass = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.__varOfClass = 1234
```

Добавить геттер и сеттер:

```
class Parent:
  # ...
  
  def get_var_of_class(self):
      return self.__varOfClass
      
  def set_var_of_class(self, value):
      self.__varOfClass = value
```

Условно переопределить в `__init__` дочернего класса переменную

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.varOfClass = 5678
        super().__init__()
```

Использовать геттер/сеттер родительского класса для доступа к его переменной:

```
child = Child() 
print(child.get_var_of_class()) # выведет 1234
child.set_var_of_class(1111) # установит значение в классе Parent
print(child.varOfClass) # выведет 5678
```